# TypeScript: Convert interface to class

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface X {
    type : string;
    val : number;
}

class X1 implements X {
    type : string;
    val : number;
}

var p1 : X[] = [{type:'a', val:8}];

for (var n in p1) {
    var p2 : X1 = p1[n];
}
var p3 : X1 = p1[0];
```

Both p2 and p3 are declared as having type X1 and are initialized with a value of type X.

The compiler happily accepts the declaration of p2, but it complains about p3 saying "Cannot convert 'X' to 'X1'".

Why this difference?

Comment: I think the compiler message is misleading. If you change the last line to `var p3 : X1 = p1["a"];` it compiles fine. Looks like X[ ] is an associative (string-indexed) array - but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Everything that implements `X` should be convertible to `X`, but not necessarily convertible to `X1`.

Here is more detail. The code below shows a simple example. Essentially, if you have something of type `X` (interface) it could be implemented by either `X1` (class) or `X2` (class).

While you can downgrade a type (from the implementation down to the interface) you can't upgrade a type (from the interface to a specific implementation) because you can't guarantee that what you have is compatible.

Another way of looking at this is that you can make something *less* specific than it is, but you can't make something *more* specific than it is.

```
interface X {
    type : string;
    val : number;
}

class X1 implements X {
    type : string;
    val : number;
}

class X2 implements X {
    type: string;
    val: number;
    myMethod() {

    }
}

var x1 = new X1();
var x2 = new X2();

var exampleA: X = x1; // happy
var exampleB: X = x2; // happy

var exampleC: X1 = exampleA; // Not happy...
```

The upshot of all of this is that you need to cast it:

```
var exampleC: X1 = <X1>exampleA; // happy...
```

But be cautious, because you could do this, which wouldn't actually work:

```
var exampleC: X2 = <X2>exampleA; // seems happy...
exampleC.myMethod(); // oh dear!
```

**Update**

In respect of this piece of code...

```
for (var n in p1) {
    var p2 : X1 = p1[n];
}
```

In JavaScript this isn't equivalent to a `foreach` loop. What this is normally used for is iterating over properties in an object and [when you use it on an array it will only show explicitly set indexes (not all items)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays). To iterate over an array, you should be using:

```
for (var i = 0; i < p1.length; i++) {
    var p2 : X1 = p1[i]; // same warning as before
}
```

So how come TypeScript allows `p1[n]` to be allocated to an `X1` variable? Interesting question and the answer lies here...

If you hover over `p1[n]` you'll see a type of `X[]` - this is the type of `p1`, not the type of `p1[n]`. If you check this example, you'll find that `p1[n]` is of type `any`:

```
var example = p1['test']; // I used 'test' because n is a string.
```

Because it is of type `any` the compiler allows you to tell it to treat it as an `X1`. So you are converting from `any` to `X1` not from `X` to `X1` as you might have thought.

Comment: That is indeed what I expected. But why does the compiler then accept my declaration of p2?

Comment: Short answer: `p1[n]` is of type `any`, not of type `X`. Detailed explanation added to my answer.

Comment: Why do i have to repeat all values of X in X1? is there a way they could be inherited?

Comment: That was just to illustrate the point about types. You can absolutely inherit, using the `extends` keyword.